# Prove that $f$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, f\in C(\mathbb{C})$ and $f\in Hol(\mathbb{D})$ (the unit disk). $f \neq 0$ for every $|z| \geq 1$ and $f(z) \to 1$ as $z \to \infty$. Show that $f$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$.

I was thinking about using the argument principle by showing that for large enough $R$, the winding number of $f\circ Re^{2\pi i t}$ around 0 must be 0, but for that I need $f \in Hol(\mathbb{C})$.

Anyone has another idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need that $f$ is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ for that. Do you know what a homotopy is?

Comment: @DanielFischer Don't I need a meromorphic function for the argument principle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: Holomorphic implies meromorphic.  ("holomorphic over one" is trivially meromorphic)

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I think I understand what Robert is saying.

Comment: If you insist on the argument principle, yes. But for the winding number, continuous suffices, and the winding number is invariant under homotopies. Since $f(Re^{it})$ has winding number $0$ for large $R$, it also has winding number $0$ for $r_0 < R < 1$, where you know that $f$ has no zeros in $r_0 < \lvert z\rvert < 1$ (which you have by continuity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winding number can be defined for any continuous function on a curve, not just a holomorphic one.  As you deform the curve, that winding number will still be constant as long as the function doesn't hit $0$.